# How to implement redirection rule for Spaces in iirf file?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iirf

We tried so many ways, to redirect from one OLD URL to desired URL.
eg:
1)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.example.com)$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=%20%20%20%2011111111111%20%20($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)name=product-name($|&)
RewriteRule ^/products/site.aspx$ http://example.com/en/products/product [L,R=301]
```

result: It is not working.

2)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(http://www.example.com/)$
RedirectMatch 301 "^(.+?) +$" $1
RedirectRule ^/products/site.aspx\?sku=\%20\%20\%20\%201111111111\%20\%20\&name=product-name$ http://www.example.com/en/product [I,R=301]
```

result: It is not working.

we replaced space with **\s** and **** but the result is not working.
Please help us on this.